# splitting tweets based on time

Tags: python, twitter

I have a collection of tweets in json format in a file. The "created_at" key in each tweets looks like:

```
Sun May 28 23:59:59 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:58 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:58 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:58 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:58 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:57 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:57 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:57 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:57 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:56 +0000 2017
Sun May 28 23:59:56 +0000 2017
```

I would like to collect tweets for every 10 second interval and do some calculations on the tweets (e.g. consider from Sun May 28 23:59:59 +0000 2017 to Sun May 28 23:59:49 +0000 2017) and next step from Sun May 28 23:59:49 +0000 2017 to Sun May 28 23:59:39 +0000 2017 and so on). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module to create a dataframe from the json with `df = pd.read_json(filename)` and use [TimeGrouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to group time intervals `grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("10s"))`. Then you can iterate through the groups with `for name, group in grouped:`

```
df = pd.read_json(filename)
grouped = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("10s"))

for name, group in grouped:
    ...
```